# How to tell if PDO is emulating statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Regardless of whether the PDO is executed with `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to **TRUE** of **FALSE**, how to tell if PDO is actually emulating the statements or if they are processed by the native driver?

Comment: Not sure if it would be possible as the whole purpose of it is to hide to the php code if PDO is emulating or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it is unavailable as a PDO connection handler attribute because this setting can be altered at runtime.
But it is possible to get it for the statement handler.
So, if you want to know emulation status before starting any actual statement, a fake query have to be used. As an additional proof, my little trick on revealing emulation can be used:

```
try {
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $sth  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1");
    $emul = $sth->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);
    var_dump($emul);
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 LIMIT ?,?");
    $sth->execute(array(1,2));    

    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);
    $sth  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1");
    $emul = $sth->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);
    var_dump($emul);
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 LIMIT ?,?");
    $sth->execute(array(1,2));    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

outputs

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near ''1','2'' at line 1
```

means in the second case PDO just emulates, and thus make values formatted as strings which causes a parse error.

Though I don't see much use for such information. Why not to just set it to whatever condition you want?